# Access 2016 - update Application Title - properties not found

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Did upgrade and application from access 2003 to access 2016

the following code

```
CurrentDb.Properties("AppTitle").value = "Test Client"
```

give me a properties not found error

How can I fix it ?

Comment: http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=2040994 - seems MSDN is wrong.

Comment: Thank for the info. the code posted works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a user-defined property, you have to define it once:

```
CurrentDb.Properties.Append CurrentDb.CreateProperty("AppTitle", dbText, "Test Client")
```

And then you can use it like you were using it

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/apptitle-property - it should be available in Access 2016.

Comment: Ah, it works, though. Like I said, you need to define it once